# Create Keywork/Page Object framework: Selenium or Protractor?

Tags: excel, selenium, protractor, pageobjects, gui-test-framework

My company's web application is Angular based ?

Is it a good idea to implement Page Object/Keyword based test automation framework using Protractor ?

As of now what I have done it, I have 1 spec file which gets called, which in turn calls a test case execution function. That function reads the excel file which have few test cases (eventually I will have more such excel file with multiple test cases in it), and then executes the test cases after forming functions from excel data. This is done by looping. The functions are implemented as Page Object.

I see 2 problems here
1. Reporting: Creating test case and/or test step based html reports with screenshots (using protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter).
2. By default 1 spec can take only 11 mins to execute.

Is this a good approach ? Should I stick to Selenium or there is a way to move forward in Protractor ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say stick to Selenium. This advice is based upon:

1. Personal experience building a keyword based automation framework using Selenium. It's proven to work and it's the highest desired skill in Automation today.
2. Much larger community compared to Protractor. Any obstacles you run into will be much easier to debug/fix because of the huge selenium community.
3. Plays well with many languages, and other test automation tools you will likely be using.

That's my 5 cents. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: do you think that should be true even if my company's web application is angular based ? I understand that we can use the angular objects in the xpath to uniquely identify in selenium, but just curious.

Comment: It should work. Anything in the GUI you cannot automate, if it generally stays the same, can be done with a little use of Sikuli as well.